# itertools.ifilter Vs. filter Vs. list comprehensions

Tags: python, function, module, built-in

I am trying to become more familiar with the `itertools` module and have found a function called `ifilter`.

From what I understand, it filters and iterable based on the given function and returns an iterator over a list containing the elements of the iterable on which the function evaluates to `True`.

**Question 1**: is my understanding thus far correct?

**Question 2**: aside from the fact that this returns and iterator, how is it different from the built-in `filter` function?

**Question 3** Which is faster?

From what I can tell, it is not. Am I missing something? (I ran the following test)

```
>>> itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x%2, range(5))
<itertools.ifilter object at 0x7fb1a101b210>
>>> for i in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: x%2, range(5)): print i
... 
1
3
>>> filter(lambda x: x%2, range(5))
[1, 3]
>>> function = lambda x: x%2
>>> [item for item in range(5) if function(item)]
[1,3]
```

Comment: What output did you expect?  `range(5)` will give you `[0,1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: note that most usages of filter can be replaced by a guard on a generator/list expression: `list(x for x in range(5) if x%2)`

Comment: Note that in 3.x, `itertools.ifilter` no longer exists, and `filter` behaves lazily.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The example below includes a number generator that prints a message immediately before yielding the number, shows up how `filter()` first builds the list, then runs through that and filters it. Whereas `itertools.ifilter` filters as it goes, never building a list. If you're filtering 500,000 significant things, you want `ifilter`, so you're not building a list.

```
import itertools

def number_generator():
    for i in range(0, 3):
        print "yield", i
        yield i
    print "stopping"

function = lambda x: x > 0

numbers = number_generator()
print "itertools.ifilter:"
for n in itertools.ifilter(function, numbers):
    print n

print "\nfilter:"
numbers = number_generator()
for n in filter(function, numbers):
    print n
```

Output:

```
itertools.ifilter:
yield 0
yield 1
1
yield 2
2
stopping

filter:
yield 0
yield 1
yield 2
stopping
1
2
```

Answer (score 24):

Your understanding is correct: the only difference is that `ifilter` returns an iterator, while using `filter` is like calling:

```
list(ifilter(...))
```

You may also be interested in what [PEP 289](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) says about filter and ifilter:

> List comprehensions greatly reduced the need for `filter()` and `map()`. Likewise, generator expressions are expected to minimize the need for `itertools.ifilter()` and `itertools.imap()`. [...]

Also note that `ifilter` became `filter` in Python-3 (hence removed from itertools).

Answer (score 5):

`ifilter` returns a generator, not a list.

Generators create their items on the fly when needed, instead of allocating the entire list first. That's the only difference between `ifilter` and `filter`

Comment: A generator is an iterator, and to be strict it returns a itertools.ifilter object.

Answer (score 2):

Here, you can see the diference:

[filter(function, iterable)](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter): **Construct a list** from those elements of iterable for which function returns true.

[itertools.ifilter(predicate, iterable)](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter): **Make an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)** that filters elements from iterable returning only those for which the predicate is True.

This means that to obtain 'ifiltered' items you should iterate with returned iterator, but 'filter' returns all elements in a list with out iteration needed.