# Idiomatically negate a filter

Tags: python, filter, functional-programming, negation

What's the most idiomatic way of writing a `filter` with a negation?

Example:

```
is_even= lambda x : x % 2 == 0
odd_numbers= filter( lambda x: not is_even(x), range(10) )
```

Of course, you can just use list comprehensions - but then you needn't use `filter` anyway

In case anyone wonders, I've stumbled upon this while trying to [split a list based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition)

Comment: In case anyone wonders, I'm trying to [split a list based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949098/python-split-a-list-based-on-a-condition)

Comment: Is that missin `)` a typo?

Comment: Damn, you edited it 1s after I posted. That's too fast :P ..

Comment: Can you tell us what you're actually trying to do? A broader description please. What's wrong with what you posted?

Comment: @ReutSharabani I mentioned that in the comments, but I'll move it to the question itself. There's nothing *wrong* with what I wrote, I was just wondering if there's a more idiomatic or less verbose way of doing it

Comment: There is no need to write two lambda functions. How about `odd = filter(lambda x: x % 2, range(10))`?

Comment: The `itertools` module has [ifilterfalse()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilterfalse), which filters for elements where the function returns False. ([itertools.filterfalse()](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) in Python 3). No built-in equivalent, but `not` seems simple enough.

Comment: @HansThen For the sake of the example, assume `is_even` is already defined

Comment: @Lack `ifilterfalse` seems exactly what I was looking for, and exists for python 2. If you care to submit an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Great. I tried to make the difference between Python 2 and 3 clear in the answer. Your example (in the question) actually gives different results in 2 and 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `itertools` module includes both [ifilter()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) and [ifilterfalse()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilterfalse), which filter elements where the function returns `True` and `False` respectively.

```
odd_numbers = ifilterfalse(is_even, range(10))
```

Note that, in Python 2, there is a difference between `filter` and `ifilter`: `odd_numbers` here would be an iterator, while filter() would give a list (see [itertools.ifilter Vs. filter Vs. list comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8994319/itertools-ifilter-vs-filter-vs-list-comprehensions)). If you actually want to build a list, your example with `not` seems fine, assuming you are set on using `filter` - list comprehensions may be more 'idiomatic' ([List filtering: list comprehension vs. lambda + filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013449/list-filtering-list-comprehension-vs-lambda-filter)).

In Python 3, [filter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) constructs an iterator, not a list, and [itertools.filterfalse()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse) is the complement.

Comment: Does anyone have any insight into why the authors chose `ifilterfalse` instead of `ireject`?

Answer (score 4):

Splitting based on a predicate is called a `partition`. I would find it more idiomatic to implement `partition` as a separate function rather than repeat its internals specifically for odd and even numbers.  Python 3's [Itertools Recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) has the following implementation:

```
def partition(pred, iterable):
    'Use a predicate to partition entries into false entries and true entries'
    # partition(is_odd, range(10)) --> 0 2 4 6 8   and  1 3 5 7 9
    t1, t2 = tee(iterable)
    return filterfalse(pred, t1), filter(pred, t2)
```

It uses `filterfalse` (as described by @Lack) and `tee` defined in that module.  So your highest-level code would look like:

```
odds, evens = partition(is_even, range(10))
```

Comment: Yes, this is a better solution to the actual problem if you are using both parts of the list.

Comment: This is probably worth posting in the question I linked to, as nobody mentioned it yet. My question in particular was more motivated by curiosity than the practical need to solve the actual partitioning (for which there's a lot of answers already)